# WiX fails to launch custom action with .NET Framwork 4

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I use this code (defined inside Product node) to launch a simple custom action

```
<!-- Run as admin -->
<Property Id="Privileged" Value="1" />
 <!-- .NET Framework must be 4.6-->
<PropertyRef Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_46_OR_LATER_INSTALLED" />
<Condition Message="You must install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 or higher.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_46_OR_LATER_INSTALLED]]>
</Condition>

<Binary Id="Ctav8.CustomAction.CA.dll"
        SourceFile="$(var.Ctav8.CustomAction.TargetDir)Ctav8.CustomAction.CA.dll" />

<CustomAction Id="CustomAction1"
              Return="check"
              Execute="immediate"
              BinaryKey="Ctav8.CustomAction.CA.dll"
              DllEntry="CustomAction1" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CustomAction1" After="InstallFiles"  />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

And this is the simple custom action with its configuration

```
public class CustomActions
{
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
    {
        session.Message(InstallMessage.Warning, new Record
        {
            FormatString = "test"
        });

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">    
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Note: the config file is called 'CustomAction.config' and its Build Action is set to 'Content'. I tried to set 'useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy' to true and false, but the result is still the same.

If I change the .NET Framework of the custom action project to 3.5, this code works fine.

What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My CustomAction config looks like this

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">     
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</startup>
```

And it works with target .Net 4.5. Maybe you just have to flip the supportedRuntime tags.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

This works with .NET Framework 4.6.1